# Low-Memory Traversal of Database Table

Tags: c#, performance, sql-server-2008

I have a database with a large number of records that are Date/Time stamped.  I need to traverse through these records (in chronological order) and perform some analysis on them.

The database is too large to pull in every record at once, so I thought of pulling in a few weeks/days/hours/etc at a time.  The problem I'm having is that no matter what I've tried, the database (SQL Server) just uses all the memory on my machine.  Even after the application is closed, `sqlservr.exe` is still using all of my memory.  It typically uses about 1.8 GB of memory, no matter if my "batches" only contain 10 records or 1,000,000.

The question is: How can I query the database to get "batches" of records at a time, without the database consuming every bit of memory?

I am using the `System.Data.SqlClient` libraries.  Here is a bit of pseudo-code:

```
String file = "C:\\db.mdf";
String connString = @"Data Source=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename="C:\db.mdf";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
conn.Open();

DateTime start = DateTime.MinValue;
DateTime end = DateTime.MaxValue;

while()
{
   // This should query for 1 hour at a time (but I should be able to change the time interval)
   // I would like for the memory usage to be proportional to the time interval

   String query = "SELECT * From MyTable WHERE Date BETWEEN '" + start.ToString() + "' AND '" + end.ToString() + "'";
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
   SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

   while(reader.Read())
      ProcessRecord(ref reader);

   start = end;
   end = end.AddHours(1);
}

conn.Close();
```

C#
.NET 3.5
SQL Server 2008

Thanks.

Comment: "the database (SQL Server) just uses all the memory on my machine". If you don't restrict SQL Server to an certain amount of memory, it will grab as much memory as it can, for obvious performance reasons. The general advice is to have SQL Server run on a dedicated machine (not shared with IIS for instance).

Comment: Why do you pass `reader` as `ref` to the `ProcessRecord`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is normal, SQL Server will use all available memory [unless configured differently](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178067.aspx).

Sql Server Express will release the memory when your other applications request more, but it will try to use all the memory it can to cache query plans and data.

Quote from the linked article:

> The following example sets the max server memory option to 4 GB:

```
 exec sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1; 
 GO 
 RECONFIGURE; 
 GO
 exec sp_configure 'max server memory', 4096; 
 GO 
 RECONFIGURE; 
 GO
 exec sp_configure 'show advanced options', 0;
 RECONFIGURE;  
 GO
```

*Do note* that `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` implement `IDisposable`, so you usually would want to wrap them in a `using` clause.

Answer (score 2):

Filip's answer is correct, that that's how SQL Server is set up to behave.

The reason that's the default is typically database servers are run on a dedicated machine that's running almost nothing except for the database and the #1 concern is database speed.  You usually want to keep as much as possible in memory so it minimizes how often it needs to hit the disk.

An alternative to programatically configuring the setting, you can use Sql Server Management Studio (SSMS) to change the configuration.  Connect to your database, right-click on it and go to Properties.  In the Memory page you can configure the maximum memory the database will use.

Answer (score 1):

A `SqlDataReader` will stream the results. As long as you don't hold on to the data returned by a record from the reader, the .NET garbage collector will collect all that data (at undeterministic times). In other words, your `while(reader.Read()) ProcessRecord(reader);` will work just fine. .NET will not load the complete set into memory (unless you do so explicitly, for instance by using a `DataSet` or `DataTable`).